# How to suppress "item already in cart" error notice in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am running a simple site that sells one product in one quantity. Imagine I only have a homepage and a checkout page.

Visitors use a "buy now" button to go from home to checkout, which also adds this one product to the cart; a pretty seamless experience.

However, when they would go back to home, and make the same step, they would be met with an error notice that the product cannot be added to the cart again.

How do I suppress this error notice?

*I am answering this Q&A style for others, because I wish I would have found this many hours ago.*

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to still retain the Error prompt in the WooCommerce files, -otherwise multi products can be added-, but to empty its content.

From your dashboard go to `plugins` --> `plugin editor` --> `WooCommerce` --> `plugin files` --> `class-wc-cart.php`
In this file look for the `add_to_cart()` function

Here you fill find the line:

```
throw new Exception( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), $message ) );
```

Comment it out and replace it as follows (maybe leave a notice so you'll be able to find what you've edited in the future):

```
//throw new Exception( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), $message ) );

throw new Exception(); // Commented to suppress error notice - MGPoirot was here
```